# Regex: Check If String Contains A Single Instance of the Letter "A" or "B"

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net, visual-studio

I am completely new to the world of Regular Expressions, and was wondering if someone could provide me with some assistance on getting an expression going.

In my scenario, I need to check if a string contains one letter, and the one letter can either be an A or B. Only phrases with a single letter as **A** or **B** are permitted.

[image]

Ideally the expression would identify the "Good" values as matches and reject the "Bad" values due to containing multiple letters and not a single **A** or **B**.

Any help would be very much appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: [^ab]*[ab]{1}[^ab]* => this regex may help. [^ab]* means; not a and not b characters can be seen any number of times (maybe zero time). [ab]{1} means; a or b characters should be seen once. A more efficient regex suggestion may come. If your only criterion is the number of letters, I suggest you create a Count method (use your language's method if available). You can get better performance.

Comment: @AdemCatamak - If you look at each piece of that regex, you'll see there are very obvious shortcomings. Something like "XYZ" will pass the first and third part. Since they also allows for no matches, you could also get away with "ABABABABA" (all assuming case insensitivity of course).

Comment: What part of this task are you stuck on?  You've specified the problem but not what, if anything, you've attempted to solve it, so, as written, the "assistance" and "help" you've requested look like euphemisms for "Please do this for me."  Also, why have you tagged both C# and VB.NET and how did you decide that this must be solved with regular expressions?  A simple `foreach` loop with a counter might be a more performant and straightforward solution.

Comment: `If UBound(Split("012345A12A34", "A")) <> 1 then MsgBox "No Match on A"` repeat for B.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the result and regex is not mandatory, you could use a simple expression as below

```
bool result = word.Where(Char.IsLetter).Count() == 1 && (word.Contains('A') || word.Contains('B'));
```

Comment: You can simplify this slightly and do the first check just in the `Count` with: `word.Count(Char.IsLetter) == 1`. No need for `Where`.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb yep. That's correct

Answer (score 2):

The expression `^[^A-Z]*[AB][^A-Z]*$` matches a string containing exactly one letter that is either `A` or `B`.

Explanation:

```
^        Matches the start of the string.
[^A-Z]   Matches any character that is not a lette
*        Means zero or more of the previous item, thus
         [^A-Z]* Matches zero or more characters that are not letters
[AB]     Matches either an `A` or a `B`
[^A-Z]*  Matches zero or more characters that are not letters
$        Matches the end of the string
```

If the string should contain at least one character before and after the `A` or `B` then the pattern should be modified to be `^[^A-Z]+[AB][^A-Z]+$`. Using the `+` means matching be one or more of the previous item whereas the `*` means zero or more.

The pattern `[A-Z]` matches any letter. `[^A-Z]` matches any character that is not a letter. Similarly `[AB]` matches either an `A` or a `B`. `[^AB]` matches any character that is not `A` or `B`, but this pattern is not needed here. Putting these together gives t

Comment: Good but as a sidenote it accepts lowercase `aAb` and if input is unicode it would match such as [`МAН`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%5eA-Z%5d*%5bAB%5d%5b%5eA-Z%5d*%24&i=%d0%9cA%d0%9d) which can be avoided by use of `\P{L}` instead of `[^A-Z]`